# VBA: repeat a value a number of times

Tags: vba

I have an input table in range A2: D6, I want each value in input range to be shown 4 times in output
range A8: D27

Below is the code it is copying only one value to the output range.

Could you please guide me on how to change this VBA code to get the desired result as shown in the below picture.

```
Sub RepeatData()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim lr As Integer
Dim C As Integer

Range(("A8"), Range("D10000")).ClearContents


lr = Range(("A1"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Count
C = 4

Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
Set InputRng = Range("A2", Range("d" & lr))

Set OutRng = Range("a8")
  
         For Each Rng In InputRng.Rows
                 xValue = Rng.Range("A1", "a1").Value
                xNum = 4 ' No. of times to repeat
                OutRng.Resize(xNum, C).Value = xValue
                Set OutRng = OutRng.Offset(xNum, 0)

            Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use these strange Range constructs?? `Range(("A1"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))`  or `Rng.Range("A1", "a1").Value`  or `Range(("A8"), Range("D10000"))` ?? Why not just `Range("A1:D1000")`

Comment: Thank you teylyn for your time and, when i change the range from Range("A1:"a1").value to Range("A1:D1000"), this will give the out put result but not in the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are looping through entire input rows, so I would propose a solution copying entire rows.

```
Sub RepeatData()
    Dim inputWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim outputRangeStart As Range
    Dim rowToBeCopied As Range
    Dim firstFreeRow As Range
    Dim numberOfOutputRows As Integer
    Dim outputRange As Range
    
    ' set all params
    Set inputWorksheet = Sheet1
    Set inputRange = inputWorksheet.Range("A2:D5")
    Set outputRangeStart = inputWorksheet.Range("A8")
    numberOfOutputRows = 4
    
    ' clean output range
    Range(outputRangeStart, outputRangeStart.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).ClearContents
    
    ' copy values
    For Each rowToBeCopied In inputRange.Rows
        Set firstFreeRow = FindFirstFreeCell(outputRangeStart)
        Set outputRange = ExtendRangeByNumberOfRows(firstFreeRow, numberOfOutputRows)
        
        rowToBeCopied.Copy
        outputRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next rowToBeCopied
End Sub

Function FindFirstFreeCell(startFrom As Range) As Range
    If IsEmpty(startFrom) Then
        Set FindFirstFreeCell = startFrom
    ElseIf IsEmpty(startFrom.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        Set FindFirstFreeCell = startFrom.Offset(1, 0)
    Else
        Set FindFirstFreeCell = startFrom.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
End Function

Function ExtendRangeByNumberOfRows(rangeToBeExtended As Range, numberOfRows As Integer) As Range
    Set ExtendRangeByNumberOfRows = Range(rangeToBeExtended, rangeToBeExtended.Offset(numberOfRows - 1, 0))
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Edward, yes this works perfectly, Excellent piece of code, works superbly.